# Override Argo Workflows generateName from Sensor

Tags: github, argo-workflows, argo-events, argo

I'm looking into customizing workflow names. I see that `argo submit --generate-name` can override the `.metadata.generateName` property, but does anyone know if this is possible with a `Sensor` that triggers a `Workflow`?

I'm using a GitHub event to trigger these workflows, but it would be nice to pull the repository name out of the event and set it as the `generateName` on the Workflow.

Here's an example of what I was hoping would work, but doesn't seem to as far as I can tell. Maybe I've got the syntax wrong? Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

(Note, I've removed a large part of this sensor so that just the important parts are shown. Basically, I want to parse a GitHub event payload for the repository name. Set it on the workflow arguments. Then use those to override the workflow's `generateName` property.)

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: github-sensor
spec:
  dependencies:
    - name: github-webhook-sensor
      eventSourceName: github-events
      eventName: github

  triggers:
    - template:
        name: github
        k8s:
          group: argoproj.io
          version: v1alpha1
          resource: workflows
          operation: create
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                generateName: {{ workflow.parameters.name }}
              spec:
                arguments:
                  parameters:
                  - name: "git-repository-name"


          parameters:
          # Parameter: git-repository-name
          - src:
              dependencyName: github-webhook-sensor
              dataKey: body.repository.name
            dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this to prepend the generated name with the repo name (and a hypen):

```
          ...
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                generateName: "-"
              spec:
                arguments:
                  parameters:
                  - name: "git-repository-name"


          parameters:
          - src:
              dependencyName: github-webhook-sensor
              dataKey: body.repository.name
            dest: metadata.generateName
            operation: prepend
          # Parameter: git-repository-name
          - src:
              dependencyName: github-webhook-sensor
              dataKey: body.repository.name
            dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
```

You can also use *name* instead of *generateName*, but I'm not sure how that will behave if multiple triggers come.